# How to play videos in ExeOutput for PHP using Chromium engine

Tags: php, video, exe, chromium

I am using ExeOutput to convert PHP Projects to a standalone executable.

I need to play videos in my application using the *Chromium* engine but it is not working. It works fine, if we use the *Trident* engine, but I have to use *Chromium* engine only.

How can I play videos using *Chromium* engine in my EXE?

Comment: Much more information is needed, e.g. what isn't working exactly and what platform are you on? Currently, your question is too broad and we can only guess the root cause.

Comment: Add more info about your post. What is your source code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the html video tag

Like this:

```
<video src="link to mp4"></video>
```